# Android - Can I get the audio data for playback from the audio mixer?

Tags: android, audio

I want to capture the audio playing on android phones.

As for voice call audio source, I can do it by using AudioRecord.
But I don't know are there any ways to get other audio sources (for example, the music other app is playing).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> As for voice call audio source, I can do it by using AudioRecord

Only if by "voice call audio source" you mean the microphone.

> But I don't know are there any ways to get other audio sources (for example, the music other app is playing).

If the device is in speakerphone mode, you can capture it via the microphone.

Otherwise, you have no rights to access other apps' audio output.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I can capture it only via mic? Can't i do like Visualizer getWaveForm when audioSession is 0?